# UITableViewCells with different cell sizes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is it possible to have a UITableView that has a fixed height for all cells, except for the cell at the top (index 0)?

If so, how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the tableView’s delegate to an object that responds to `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

If your topmost cell does not have to be a UITableViewCell, you can also use a section header instead of a cell. See same [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your app, but you might want to have a look at `tableHeaderView` instead of trying to change the top row. [Here's a link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView)

Comment: This is interesting, is there any way I can create my view in a XIB and then assign the tableHeaderView property?

Comment: Yeah, you can create a view however you want and then set `tableHeaderView` equal to that view. Remember to size it appropriately.

Comment: I've found it's almost always easier to deal with UITableViews programmatically than using an XIB, IMHO.